# How to create skydome model in Blender?

Tags: mesh, normals, skybox

[image]How do you make a *skydome* as used in this [Sketchfab object](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sunset-church-acd66b6d3fc24329b3026690669bc61b).

A *skydome* is an alternative to an HDRI for providing sky-like lighting. It's an actual dome that you place your scene inside, the way a model fits inside a snow globe.

In [this old video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWptDU3xG60)  the author unwrapped half of a sphere and then flipped the normals; but that doesn't appear to work in modern versions of Blender, because the material creation section is for the Blender internal render engine.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: hello, it's hard to guess why it doesn't work in your case, maybe pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that when I edited the question.  The video is for the Blender Internal Render Engine, so the part for making the material doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique in the video doesn't appear to work because the second half of the video talks about how to add an image for an old version of the Blender render engine that's no longer supported.

Here's a version that works in Blender 2.8x and Blender 2.9x for the Cycles render engine.

- Create a sphere
- Scale it up to the desired size.
- Apply the scale.
- Enter edit mode and delete the lower half of the sphere.  This is your skydome.
- While still in edit mode, hit <kbd>U</kbd> and select *unwrap* to unwrap the half dome.
- Switch to the Shading workspace and create a new material for the dome:
  [image]
- For the image texture you can pick anything, but as in the video an image that was meant to be used as a skybox is best.
- You can adjust the emission strength until you get the right level of lighting.

Alternatively, and I think your sketchfab answer does it this way, you could create a procedural texture, but the details are beyond the scope of this answer.

Example: Suzanne lit by the moon as a skydome.

[image: Suzanne lit by the moon as a skydome.]

What this looks like as a wireframe.  Note that the camera is inside the hemisphere.

[image: What it looks like as a wireframe.]

**EDIT:**

You need a different shader if you want the dome to look different inside that it does outside.  The idea here is that each face of an object has a front side and a back side, so we use the *Geometry* node to select between the two by using it to control the *Fac* input of a *Mix* shader.

In my example, the inside face of the dome is the backside, because I have *not* flipped normals, so the shader that applies the image goes into the top input of the Mix shader.

To achieve transparency from the outside, a *Transparent* shader, with its color set to white goes to bottom input.

[image: Shader with added nodes to achieve transparency]

This version works as in for the *Cycles* render engine.  If you are using EEVEE, you need to edit the material settings for the dome and change the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend*.

[image: material properties showing the Blend Mode setting]

Finally, if you want the dome to appear in a black sky, you need to change your *World* properties to give the world a black color.

Comment: while creating new material,  the Principle BSDF  node is created. What should i do with this ? Screenshot attached into my answer . Sorry im new to blender, just wanna to create model like those on Sketchfab

Comment: Delete the Principled Shader and add the emission shader, as in my example.  You could use the Principled Shader instead of the emission shader, but this way is easiest at your level.

Comment: done , now it seems to be semi-transparent in blender layout viewer, but when uploading on sketchfab it's not transparent. But in my desire, dome wall may be fully transparent from point of view and opaque on opposite site.  I'll edit my question and upload screenshot of desired result. also thankful for such detailed answer!

Comment: when you edit your question, be sure to put in information about how you are uploading to sketchfab.  It may be that whatever method you're using doesn't support backface textures.